# Image encrypting with AES c#

Tags: c#, image, encryption, aes, memorystream

I have to encrypt and decrypt Image by AES each algorithm.
I have following code that encrypt Image:

```
public static byte[] MakeEncryption(Image image, CipherMode mode, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider { Mode = mode })
            {
                aes.Key = key;
                aes.IV = iv;
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

                byte[] imageBytes;
                using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(mstream, image.RawFormat);
                    imageBytes = mstream.ToArray();
                }

                using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                using (MemoryStream encrypted = new MemoryStream())
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encrypted, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    input.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
                    return encrypted.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

And following code to convert byte array to Image:

```
public static Image GetImage(byte[] bytes)
        {
            Image img;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                img = Image.FromStream(ms); // this line cause to ArgumentException
            }

            return img;
            
        }
```

Every time i run my code i had the same problem:
System.ArgumentException in line with comment

Any idea what is wrong?

I tried many ways of loading image into encrypting function, many ways of using different types of Stream, nothing helped

Comment: If the `GetImage` is supposed to decrypt the stream encrypted with `MakeEncryption` then there's no single line there that creates the decryptor and uses it.

Comment: @WiktorZychla 'GetImage' is just a function to display image from bytes, without decryption. In case it used for encrypted image. i have to display image that looks like noise

Comment: How is `GetImage` supposed to **display image from bytes** is bytes are encrypted? Do you assume `Image.FromStream` supports AES encrypted byte streams?

Answer (score 1):

The [`RawFormat` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rawformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) seems to *reference* [the "file format" of the image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), e.g. `Jpeg`. It in itself may not represent a raw image in the sense that it just contains the color information for each pixel.

After encryption of the, for instance JPEG encoded image, you can of a be sure that the meta information that is required to translate the image back to a bitmap is lost during encryption. In other words, the ciphertext won't *represent* an image anymore. Decoding such an image won't result in a distorted image, it will just abort on first few bytes of the header.

You could try the [`MemoryBmp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.memorybmp?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-drawing-imaging-imageformat-memorybmp%60) to get as close to pixels as possible. But please note that an image still has other data such as the width and height encoded somewhere. The size will also be altered if you are encrypting using CBC. `Bmp` also has the raw image stored inside, but you'd have to parse the format to find the pixels.

Encrypting the entire image and just displaying a static or newly created, randomized image of the same dimensions would be much easier than trying to find each pixel and encrypting those separately (or something similar).

Comment: Thanks for the infomation. I understood that using this algorithm is acceptable when there is no need to display encrypted image, just only after decryption.
Are there any way to encrypt entire image with the ability to display it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding. Can you explain what you mean with "Thanks for the infomation. I understood that using this algorithm is acceptable when there is no need to display encrypted image, just only after decryption"? What are you trying to achieve? Which algorithm? Yes, you can encrypt the pixel data with e.g. AES-CTR, with the disadvantage that you need a place to store the IV, but you would need access to the raw pixels. It would not be easy for e.g. JPEG, hence the reference to the uncompressed MemoryBmp and Bmp formats.

Comment: Here is [repo](https:/github.com/Danshicu/5-Semester/tree/main/SiMZIIS/Laba3/bin/Debug) with images encrypted in Python.
File encrypted contains image in format i trying to achive using C# AES algorithms.Also this [file](github.com/Danshicu/5-Semester/blob/main/SiMZIIS/Laba3/CryptoCipher.cs) contains code that keeps first 55 bytes of PNG. Bytes after 55 are encrypted later and written with first 55 of original PNG to file. As a result, i had fully black displayable image that after decryption 55-... bytes becomes original image. Can i encrypt entire img, display it encrypted and decrypt back?